# When is enthusiast badge awarded?

Tags: support, badges

I have been visiting the site from more than 30 consecutive days, but I haven got enthusiast badge, why?

And also wanted to know,

For the fanatic badge, its 100 consecutive days, would you get 3 enthusiast badge before getting fanatic badge?

Comment: I think you need to stay some minimum time on the site for it to count as a visit.

Answer (score 5):

You've only *just* got to 30 *consecutive* days. The badge system can take a little while to pick these up. Wait to see what happens over the course of the next 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

Also note that you can click on the "visited" field in your user profile to get a calendar that tells you what dates you visited.

[image]

Comment: Great!  Now I can be sure that I _don't_ get the Fanatic badge.  Incidentally, once I'd clicked to get the calendar, I couldn't figure out how to get rid of it again.

Comment: @Andrew: Simply reload?!

Comment: @doncherry: Wot no fancy buttons to click?  I feel cheated!

Answer (score 5):

The Enthusiast badge is awarded only once. So you would get this badge a short time after you visited for 30 consecutive days, and if you exceed 100 days you would get the Fanatic badge.